# Send mail functionality not working

Tags: php

I was trying to send mail using following method. But if I use `$headers` the functionality is not working.Otherwise it is working fine. Where I went wrong?

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{

$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
$phone=$_REQUEST['phn'];
$country=$_REQUEST['country'];
$company=$_REQUEST['company'];
$subject=$_REQUEST['subject'];
$enquiry=$_REQUEST['message'];

$subject = "xyz.com-".$subject;
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$name."\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n";

$msg="
<table><tr><td>Name</td><td>".$name."</td></tr>
<tr><td>Email:</td><td>".$email."</td></tr>
<tr><td>Contact Number:</td><td>".$phone."</td></tr>
<tr><td>Country:</td><td>".$country."</td></tr>
<tr><td>Company:</td><td>".$company."</td></tr>
<tr><td>Message:</td><td>".$enquiry."</td></tr>
</table>";

if(mail("myName@gmail.com",$subject,$msg,$headers))
{
$msg1="Email Sent Successfully";

}
else
{
$msg1='Mail not sent. Please try again';

}
}
```

Comment: I think the value of $name in From: should be an email.

Comment: Always google before you post..

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
$headers .= "From: ".$name."\r\n";
```

with

```
$headers .= "From: ".$name."<".$email.">"."\r\n";
```

Everything else seems good, cheers!

Comment: You'll still need the `.=` else it'll overwrite the previous variable declaration and not append to it.

Comment: yes my bad, thanks for identifying..

Comment: @zzlalani:: Tried this but not working. If I removed the `From`, mail is being delivered without any issues.

Comment: well you should have a look at this http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3342

Answer (score 0):

Do not use mail() directly, but find one of the many premade classes for mail sending from the net!

As you dig deeper into mailsending, you WILL face alot of problems, which already have been addressed in mail libraries such as PHPMailer or alike.

Besides of that, your code is a perfect example on "how to build a spam mail application" because it is susceptible for Mailheader-Injection attacks!